# Regular expression, find a word between two words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this string

```
<p/><ul><li>test1<p/></li><li>test2<p/></li></ul><p/>
```

What i attempt to do is extract all the "p" tag within the "li" tag, but not the "p" tag outside of it.

I'm only able so far to
extract all the "li" tags by

```
\<li\>(.*?)\</li\>
```

I'm lost at how to extract the "p" tag within it.

Any pointer is greatly appreciated it!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Parse HTML with an HTML parser. HTML is not a "regular language" and therefore cannot be parsed correctly with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it uses lookahead so that the LI is not part of the selection.

```
(?<=<li>)(.*?<p/?>.*?)(?=</li>)
```

P.S. You also need to fix your HTML because the way you have P tags is not right. The Regex works on this HTML below.

```
<ul><li><p>test1<p/></li><li><p>test2<p/></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is a lot more reliable to use an HTML parser instead of a regex. Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<p/><ul><li>test1<p/></li><li>test2<p/></li></ul><p/>");
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> result = doc.DocumentNode
                                  .Descendants("li")
                                  .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("p"));
```

Comment: Thanks Marks. Actually, I'm parsing bbcode out a bunch of text and after the last iteration of converting bbcode, the text came out like that, so I need to do a bit clean up. But thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<li>(.*?<p/?>.*?)</li>
```

Will match all content between `<li>` which also contain a `<p/>`. If you just want to match the `<p/>` then:

```
(?<=<li>).*?(<p/?>).*?(?=</li>)
```

Will have group 1 match the `<p/>` tag.

Comment: You and James are Regx Nija! Thanks a lot